# Oracle Add procedure using pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

[image]

The Procedure is like below! 
I'm new to oracle. As i copy the sqlserver procedure to oracle and change some parts. It will be a great thxs help me solve this !

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_GetAdminResource
(
AdminId IN NVARCHAR2,
p_ResultSet        OUT  sys_refcursor
) 
AS
BEGIN
WITH T AS(
    SELECT T1.ResId, T1.UpResId
      FROM SYS_Resource T1
     WHERE T1.IsActive = 1
       AND T1.ResId IN (SELECT DISTINCT T2.ResId
                          FROM SYS_RoleResource T2
                         WHERE T2.RoleId IN
                               (SELECT T3.RoleId
                                  FROM SYS_RoleAdministrator T3, SYS_Role T10
                                 WHERE T10.RoleId = T3.RoleId
                                   AND T10.IsActive = 1
                                   AND T3.AdminId = AdminId))),
     TT AS (SELECT *
              FROM T
            UNION ALL (SELECT T4.ResId, T4.UpResId
                        FROM SYS_Resource T4, T
                       WHERE T4.IsActive = 1
                         AND T4.ResId = T.UpResId)),
      SELECT  T5.ResId, T5.UpResId, T5.ResIcon,T5.ResName, T5.ResUrl,T5.OrderNum,T8.ActionCode
        FROM SYS_Resource T5 INTO p_ResultSet
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT T6.ResId, T6.ActionCode
               FROM SYS_RoleResource T6
              WHERE T6.RoleId IN
                    (SELECT T7.RoleId
                       FROM SYS_RoleAdministrator T7, SYS_Role T9
                      WHERE T9.RoleId = T7.RoleId
                        AND T9.IsActive = 1
                        AND T7.AdminId = AdminId)) T8 ON T5.ResId =
                                                         T8.ResId
       WHERE T5.IsActive = 1
         AND T5.ResId IN (SELECT DISTINCT TT.ResId FROM TT)
       ORDER BY T5.OrderNum ASC, T5.ResName ASC;


END SP_GetAdminResource;
```

Comment: ORA-00903 is invalid table name. Are you sure `SYS_Resource` exists and you have access to it? Is it on the same schema as your user? Do you have a synonym?

Comment: remove comma , after `AND T4.ResId = T.UpResId))`

Comment: and you have bad syntax in `FROM SYS_Resource T5 INTO p_ResultSet` move `INTO p_ResultSet` after `select statement`

Comment: Compilation errors for PROCEDURE WSBDSZ.SP_GETADMINRESOURCE

Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL SQL Statement hasn't end correctly
Line: 27
Text: FROM SYS_Resource T5 INTO p_ResultSet
Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line: 8
Text: WITH T AS

Comment: when i change to this  SELECT  T5.ResId, T5.UpResId, T5.ResIcon,T5.ResName, T5.ResUrl,T5.OrderNum,T8.ActionCode INTO p_ResultSet
        FROM SYS_Resource T5 .   it gets  error : pl/sql ora-00947 without encough values. could you help me find the problem?

Comment: @ray That's not how you assing ref_cursors. Take a look: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets

Answer (score 0):

Check below the working version of your procedure. I have put my comments in between . Please go through it and work accordingly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_GetAdminResource
(
AdminId            IN NVARCHAR2,
p_ResultSet        OUT  sys_refcursor
) 
AS
BEGIN

Open p_ResultSet for -- this is the way to use refcursor in your procedure
WITH T AS(
    SELECT T1.ResId, T1.UpResId
      FROM SYS_Resource T1
     WHERE T1.IsActive = 1
       AND T1.ResId IN (SELECT DISTINCT T2.ResId
                          FROM SYS_RoleResource T2
                         WHERE T2.RoleId IN
                               (SELECT T3.RoleId
                                  FROM SYS_RoleAdministrator T3, SYS_Role T10
                                 WHERE T10.RoleId = T3.RoleId
                                   AND T10.IsActive = 1
                                   AND T3.AdminId = t2.AdminId))), ----Check which AdminId need to be joined.I joined it with T2
    TT AS (SELECT T.ResId, T.UpResId
              FROM  T  
            UNION ALL (SELECT T4.ResId, T4.UpResId
                        FROM SYS_Resource T4, T
                       WHERE T4.IsActive = 1
                         AND T4.ResId = T.UpResId) )
                        -- ,                                 ----Extra Need to remove it
      SELECT  T5.ResId, 
              T5.UpResId 
--              T5.ResIcon,   ---Uncomment these columns in your query, I just made tables to test without these columns.
--              T5.ResName, 
--              T5.ResUrl,
--              T5.OrderNum,
--              T8.ActionCode
        FROM SYS_Resource T5 
  --      INTO p_ResultSet        -------------------------------No need to fetch into sysrefcursor.
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT T6.ResId, T6.ActionCode
               FROM SYS_RoleResource T6
              WHERE T6.RoleId IN
                    (SELECT T7.RoleId
                       FROM SYS_RoleAdministrator T7, SYS_Role T9
                      WHERE T9.RoleId = T7.RoleId
                        AND T9.IsActive = 1
                        AND T7.AdminId = t6.AdminId)) T8 ON T5.ResId =   ------Check which AdminId need to be joined.I joined it with T6
                                                         T8.ResId
       WHERE T5.IsActive = 1
         AND T5.ResId IN (SELECT DISTINCT TT.ResId FROM TT)
       ORDER BY T5.OrderNum ASC, T5.ResName ASC ;


END SP_GetAdminResource;
```